# Generating and saving XML using activex

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, activex

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><foo><bar>bar</bar></foo>'; 
        var $iframe = $('#myiframe').get(0).contentWindow;

        $iframe.document.open("text/xml", "replace");
        //$iframe.document.write(xml);

        var xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async="false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);

        $iframe.document.write(xmlDoc.xml);

        //$iframe.document.execCommand('SaveAs',true,'file.xml'); 



    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="" height="200" width="200" frameborder="0" id="myiframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, however, i have 2 questions:

1: Can I make IE understand that its an xml document its trying to save? At the moment i get filetype "*.html" when i save it. Also, it doesnt render as an xml in the iframe.

2: Is there any way to change the encoding in the generated file? At the moment its "UCS-2 Little Endian". I suppose unicode is prefered?

Thanks in advance!